# Arango schema validation for Edge collection with false additionalProperties not working

Tags: arangodb

I am using ArangoDB schema validation released in 3.7 version. Schema validation happens as expected for Document collections. But for **Edge collections** following issue comes.

- Requirement of edge: The edge should have either *id* property or no properties at all (hence *required* key is not used), and no any other properties(hence *additionalProperties* is set to false).

I used the following schema and the edge instance. But the following edge instance cannot be created as the schema validation fails.

Schema used:

```
{
  "message": "Schema validation error",
  "level": "strict",
  "rule": {
    "properties": {
      "id": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    },
    "additionalProperties": false
  }
}
```

Edge instance creation tried using ArangoDB Web Interface :

- _from: DocCollection1/t1
- _to:   DocCollection2/t2
- _key:  e1
- Document body:{}

The edge can be created if I change *additionalProperties* to *true*, but it also enables to create edges with properties with any name, which I do not need.

I have searched in Arango documentation and cannot figure out why the schema validation fails for this scenario in Edge collections. Same scenario works fine in Document collections.

**Environment**: Single node, v3.7.2, Community Edition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug that got fixed in 3.7.5:

https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues/12778
https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/pull/12967

There doesn't seem to be a workaround for 3.7.4 and earlier versions unfortunately - adding `_from` explicitly as attribute doesn't help, I suppose because it's a special field which requires internal translation.